# How to make my discord.py rewrite bot respond to other bots but not to webhooks?

Tags: discord.py

This doesn't allow the bot to respond to webhooks but it also doesn't allow the bot to respond to other bots

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
    return
  else:
    msg = message.content
    webhooks = await message.channel.webhooks()
    webhook = utils.get(webhooks, name = "Backups")
    if webhook is None:
      webhook = await message.channel.create_webhook(name = "Backups")

    await webhook.send(msg, username = message.author.name, avatar_url = message.author.avatar_url)


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for [`Message.webhook_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.webhook_id). If it's not `None` the message is sent by a webhook

```py
if message.webhook_id is not None:
   return 

...
```